# Can an Indian file multiple Schengen Visa applications at once?

Tags: germany, students

Would it be possible for an Indian to file for both student and Schengen visa at the same time?

[This previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179180/can-i-apply-for-a-student-schengen-visa-while-holding-a-tourist-visa) is not the same as this one. The previous one's accepted answer revolves around applying for a student visa after being in possession of a tourist visa. My question is rather different.  I am asking if I can open multiple visa applications at once.

By student visa I mean the long stay visa (more than year or so)

[Crossposted from](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/179199/edit)

Comment: This question was asked and answered here: [Can an Indian file for a national and a schengen visa applications at once? - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/179199/95267)